# (Google Chrome Extension) I want to click a link on a page but they all have similar hrefs

Tags: javascript

I want to click a link on a page but they all have similar hrefs

This works for clicking the first link

Code:
await executeScript("document.querySelector('a[href*="/p/"]').click()");

How do I click the 10th link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css you have method called nth-child and **nth-of-type** and **nth-child** , use that to find the element

so assuming the href is inside an unique or the span containing the 'a' tag is inside a specific parent use something like

```
await executeScript("document.querySelector('div#parentid>span:nth-child(10) a[href*="/p/"]').click()");
```

This will find the div tag with id parentid , and finds the second direct span tag child , and finds the "a" tag with mentioned href any where under the span tag

or use xpath :

```
 await executeScript("document.evaluate('(//a[contains(@href,"/p/")])[10]', document,null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue").click()
```

**Update:**

As you are using chrome extension use below steps

**Install:**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crx-extractordownloader/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda?hl=en-US

**Goto**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/donelikes-automatically-l/kpalbeafjagcohofnegkemfcbpkafhec?hl=en

**Download zip**

Right click on the above page and click download as zip

**update code**

**Update background.js**likeimage(url)" method in line 183**

```
await executeScript("document.evaluate('(//a[contains(@href,\"/p/\")])[2]', document,null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()");
```

just replace with above content

**install this modified extension**

**Goto:** chrome://extensions/

and click Load unpacked extension and select the folder where you unzipped the content of the zip file

Comment: I used this code on tryit editor 

code: document.querySelector('a[href*=\"/p/\"]:nth-child(4)').style.border = "10px 

TryIt Link:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_queryselector_attribute

It worked but it doesnt work on instagram cause the href is in a different div and the div changes so what should I do?

Comment: find the parent of that div which has that div, go up the tree until you find something unique. which element are you trying to find please add a screen shot and link

Comment: This is the link

Link:https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/110148382341970

Comment: @QuelKitz one example `.vY_QD>div>div>div>div:nth-child(3)>div:nth-child(1) a`

Comment: It changes though its not always vY_QD

Comment: @QuelKitz try this then `await executeScript("document.evaluate('(//a[contains(@href,"/p/")])[10]', document,null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue").click()`

Comment: That clicks the first picture still for some reason

Comment: it works fine what extension are you using ?

Comment: open browser console and try runnign just run `document.evaluate('(//a[contains(@href,"/p/")])[2]', document,null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click` you can see that it clicks second image

Comment: I did it in the console it didnt click anything for me

Comment: Nevermind it worked in console 1 min

Comment: sorry add click() at the end not click , `document.evaluate('(//a[contains(@href,"/p/")])[2]', document,null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()`

Comment: Yea I added that it works in console but when I added it to the google chrome extension it doesnt work it tried addin .click()");     .click()"; etc etc

Comment: Which extension are you using

Comment: DoneLikes Link:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/donelikes-automatically-l/kpalbeafjagcohofnegkemfcbpkafhec?hl=en Im modifying it to my liking I cant get it to work though its in background.js

Comment: how do you do that please explain the steps

Comment: Download CRX Extractor Link:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crx-extractordownloader/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda?hl=en-US Then go to DoneLikes Link:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/donelikes-automatically-l/kpalbeafjagcohofnegkemfcbpkafhec?hl=en and right click in a white area and click Download CRX for this extension and click Download ZIP for this extension then unzip it and to load it you have to go to google chrome developer tools and load unpacked extension and load the folder you unzipped

Comment: @QuelKitz see the updated answer you should use `await executeScript("document.evaluate('(//a[contains(@href,\"/p/\")])[2]', document,null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()");` replace line 183 with this content

Comment: see full step in the update

Comment: It didnt work it gets hung what are you using to edit the .js file? Im usin notepad

Comment: I am using notepad++ it works really well

Comment: Yea I have that too I had downloaded it for another purpose a while ago I just wasnt usin it lol but yea I got it to work

Comment: Please upvote and click the tick sign if the answer solved the issue

Comment: I did I dont kno if its the right one or not though cause other people answered too let me kno if I did the right one

Comment: Yup it worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Select them all with `document.querySelectorAll` which will give you an array and then take the `[9]`th element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Could you give me a example by usin this code? Code : await executeScript("document.querySelector('a[href*="/p/"]').click()");

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption they're all ahrefs with different text, you could look for that - eg find the element with the text of the 10th link, and look for that.

Alternatively, you can access in the dom [using querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAllselector), and then index the 10th one, by converting the [NodeList returned to an array](https://medium.com/@vladbezden/how-to-convert-nodelist-to-array-135182248e3c):

eg:

```
const nodesArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(('a[href*="/p/"]')));
```

then use `nodesArray[x]` for the xth element.

Or just iteratate through the returned list:

```
var ps = querySelectorAll(('a[href*="/p/"]')), i;

for (i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i) {
  ps[i]...... //whatever you want to do with it
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how to implement this Im doing this to a js file for a chrome extension